# intellij rider c# documentation english language

Tags: c#, .net, localization, documentation, rider

I just started with .net and Intellij Rider. I need to have spanish version of windows on my work laptop but I prefer to have everything related to code purely in english.

Right now .net documentation is in Spanish which frustrating me a lot, but I cant find a way to force english language in settings. Googling is also not very helpfull as those keywords together usually used in context of programming languages.

[Quick documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVln1.png)

Can somebody help me changing documentation language to english?

Comment: Unless it's changed, JB says English is the only language supported so it must be pulling from your machine's localization settings. Are you able to make it English by changing your OS settings to English; it may be the only way.

Comment: I understand that its probably pulling locale settings of the OS, however I cant change it because some of work software is poorly written and breaks on not spanish OS.
I am almost sure its a Rider thingy, because VS 2022 shows me english documentation

Comment: It seems you just have to install .NET Framework in English. Because there are only one language in xml-doc files is shipped...

Comment: @xtmq this was a good hint, I removed ES language pack and now documentation in English. Thank you

Comment: @Freeze glad to help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by removing ES language pack in VS installer window. Now Rider showing me english documentation as spanish is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

add a property at PreferredUILang at Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolset and Build>MSBuild global properties.

Add the PreferredUILang property with value en-US

Comment: Do you know how to change it manually? I was just testing this and that property apparently already exists so it won't be saved. Searching in the MSBuild dir returned nothing.

Comment: maybe you can do like this in windows : File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections.    For the Language Injections page to be available, the IntelliLang plugin must be enabled.

Comment: Thank you for sugestion, but it didnt worked for me. Documentation is still in spanish